# Martillo en carpeta y no deja ejecutar proyecto en Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8.2

Tengo un problema en el momento de ejecutar mi programa, me sale un martillito donde están las clases y no me lo deja ejecutar. Me aparece ese martillito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo raro es que todas las clases están ahí y los frames pero no los deja ejecutar, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿Que programa estás utilizando?

Comment: Netbeans IDE 8,2

Comment: Ocupas ser más descriptiva. Según tengo entendido el martillo es para construir el programa (compilar)  pero  no lo corre. (Moifique mi netbeans y no me da esos iconos sobre las carpetas) F6 sirve para ejecutar el programa. Verifica primero y actualiza tu pregunta con la sigiente info:

1)En la barra de tareas, ¿Hay alguna corriendo?(Abajo a la derecha normalmente). 2)Tienes seleccionado el proyecto en projects o por lo menos alguno de los ficheros? 3)Tu programa tiene clase principal? 4)Puedes abrir las clases para editarlas?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que darle clic derecho al proyecto, y dar clic en Propiedad, en algunas ocasiones el "martillo" que aparece es porque tienes algún problema con alguna librería o archivo .jar

Cuando abras la ventana de Propiedades de tu proyecto, checa las opciones de Sources y Libraries. En una de esas dos puede estar el problema. A veces solo es agregar correctamente la librería o archivo .jar o siemplemente hay que eliminar un ruta incorrecta.